# Database Storing Insert Query

Tags: asp.net, webforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;



public partial class Details : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
    string objective = " ";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
           if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
           {
               con.Open();
           }

           {
               String SQL = "SELECT TOP 2 * FROM QuestionBank ORDER BY NEWID()";
               SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con);
               DataSet login1 = new DataSet();
               Adpt.Fill(login1);

               foreach (DataRow dr in login1.Tables[0].Rows)
               {
                   objective = login1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["s_id"].ToString() + "," + login1.Tables[0].Rows[1]["s_id"].ToString();

                   Label1.Text = login1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["question"].ToString();
                   Label2.Text = login1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["question"].ToString();

                   break;
               }
           }
       }

   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e))
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into PaperTbl values('" + objective + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Answers Saved Successfully');location.href='Details.aspx'</script>");


    }
}
```

When i Click on Save Button 
then  question in the Label1 and Label2 gets changes
So the answer from textbox1 and textbox2 becomes wrong.
So while Saving the Data gets refreshed and new question gets save instead of old question. Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

***Page_Load***  is running before your ***TextBox1_TextChanged*** postback event. So the new values are populated and then saved.

See here for an explanation of page life cycle https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/

This should work:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadNew();
        }
    }

    private void LoadNew()
    {
        string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
        string objective = " ";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        {
            String SQL = "SELECT TOP 2 * FROM QuestionBank ORDER BY NEWID()";
            SqlDataAdapter Adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con);
            DataSet login1 = new DataSet();
            Adpt.Fill(login1);

            foreach (DataRow dr in login1.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                objective = login1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["s_id"].ToString() + "," + login1.Tables[0].Rows[1]["s_id"].ToString();

                Label1.Text = login1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["question"].ToString();
                Label2.Text = login1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["question"].ToString();

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into PaperTbl values('" + objective + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        LoadNew();

        Response.Write("<script>alert('Answers Saved Successfully');location.href='Details.aspx'</script>");


    }
```

Comment: Incidentally, you might show the same questions with that usage of NewID(). Also this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Sorry Mathew it was a button not textbox i have updated my code.

Comment: Answer is the same. You need to wrap your page load logic inside an !IsPostBack condition